# Example of a GET page that returns only 'OK' in its response

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, session-timeout, timeout-dialog.js

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin 'timeout-dialog' in my ASP.Net app to caution the user that his/her session is about to expire. This plugin is at: http://rigoneri.github.com/timeout-dialog.js/. It says that one of the parameters called 'keep-alive-url' is as below:

**keep_alive_url** -The url that will perform a GET request to keep the session alive. This GET expects a 'OK' plain HTTP response.

**How would I create a page in ASP.Net or simple html that would return a plain 'OK' in its http response?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

in ASP.NET code behind.

Comment: What will be in the code-front? Can I not use a simple HTML page also for this?

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me for awhile.

Some reason it needs to be a 404 Not Found

```
<cfheader statusCode="404" statusText="Not Found">
```